# How to find which program to use for a given mime type in linux?

Tags: linux, file, mime, gnome

I need to open a viewer for a given mime type. how to do that in Linux. I suppose the method would be specific to desktop environment in use. I want to do this through a C program.

Answer (score 1):

There are Gnome APIs that deal with mime-types for you (declared in headers such as `<libgnomevfs/gnome-vfs-mime-handlers.h>`) but I think that understanding what's happening under the covers is also useful.

The functions in question essentially read, parse and present certain configuration files' contents to you, and [here](http://developer.gnome.org/doc/whitepapers/SystemConfig/mime-info.html) is a clear explanation of the files that Gnome uses to associate mime types with files, i.e.:

> extension .mime in the
>   $gnome/share/mime-info directory or
>   from the ~/.gnome/mime-info directory.
>
> The file
>   $gnome/share/mime-info/gnome.mime is
>   special, as it contains the defaults
>   for gnome, and is read first. In
>   addition, the file
>   ~/.gnome/mime-info/user.mime is read
>   last.

As explain in the section "Default Keys" of this URL, keys such as `open`, `view` etc are what gives you the commands to use for various generic actions (and, via "tags", for specific named actions too).

For a C code example using the API, see e.g. the end of [this thread](http://www.nabble.com/libgnome:-gnome-open.c-td11162820.html).

Comment: i am not able to get the program given in the thread mentioned to compile. it includes a file config.h which is not present in my /usr/include/.

in addition i get a lot of compiler errors in the included header files. how to fix this?
like these:
/usr/include/glib/gconvert.h:108: error: expected declaration specifiers or ‘...’ before ‘gssize’

another error:
/usr/include/glib/gi18n-lib.h:27:2: error: #error You must define GETTEXT_PACKAGE before including gi18n-lib.h.